# Wechat : does an SDK / API exists?

Tags: api, sdk, wechat

I'm online on wechat (an instant messenger, not to be confused with weechat, that is an IRC client) and following a lot of groups for work. I'm searching for an SDK, an API set, to be able to automitize info collecting from groups and or individuals.

But i'm not aware of any way to do it.

Please, this is NOT an 'opinion' question, I'm litterally asking you if you know a way to receive data from weechat, because I cannot find it.

I see the area on weechat website where a company can ask for accces to API, but, really I cannot find other tools.

Edit 1: Chinese DOC, I think: https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/showdocument?action=dir_list&t=resource/res_list&verify=1&id=open1419318183&token=&lang=zh_CN

Edit 2: Chinese DOC more similar to a JS api :http://work.weixin.qq.com/api/doc#10029/%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E8%81%94%E7%B3%BB%E4%BA%BA%E9%80%89%E4%BA%BA%E6%8E%A5%E5%8F%A3

Obviously, use google translator !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from my OP, there are some docs, official docs, but the real problem is that to create even a simply Mini Program, we need to subscribe (paid) and also paying at one point a chinese-only page asks by country and the list simply does not include Italy, so I simply cannot subscribe.